# sendSynchronousRequest registers user before JSON response

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, post, nsdata

I am handling a registration form and I need to use a secure POST request.

If I just use `NSJSONSerialization` with the variable `data`, it works great. No errors.

The problem is that when I call the `sendSynchronousRequest` and try to call `NSJSONSerialization` on the variable `secureData`, the `registrationError` says "a user of with that email already exists".

How do I avoid this?

Here's the code I have:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:registrationURL];

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:registrationURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];

[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[postRequest setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[postRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", data.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:data];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *secureData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:postRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];

NSLog (@"%@", error);

if (secureData != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:secureData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString *registrationError = [json objectForKey:@"error"];

    NSLog(@"%@", registrationError);
}
```

**EDIT:** Here's the code without POST that does work:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:registrationURL];

if (data != nil)
{
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSString *registrationError = [json objectForKey:@"error"];

    NSLog(@"%@", registrationError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an error message from the server you are using. When you test it twice with the same email address the user is registered in the first run and already exists in the following tries.

Comment: I realize that. I test with a different email address each time. The problem is the `sendSynchronousRequest`. @eik

Comment: You get a perfect valid JSON object back, so NSURLConnection is not the culprint. OTOH to me "a user of with that email already exists" sounds suspiciously like a server message.

Comment: That is correct. When I register an email without the secure POST, I get no server message. When I register with secure POST, I always get the server message; no matter what email I use. - @eik

Comment: Do a `NSLog(@"Headers: %@", [response allHeaderFields]);`, especially the `Date` header and check whether you get a fresh response every time. Could you show the code without 'secure POST'?

Comment: I added the code that works. I also did an NSLog of [postRequest allHTTPHeaderFields]. It doesn't show a date. @eik

Comment: Ok, I assume all Parameters are already contained in `registrationURL `, basically the server ignores the body of your second 'secure' POST (no idea why you consider it to be secure) and returns "a user of with that email already exists". Just don't register the same email address twice.